# SimpleCV not Importing Correctly

Tags: python, opencv, simplecv

I just finished installing SimpleCV and all its dependencies, but am having trouble running it. If I just use this:

```
import SimpleCV
```

I don't get any errors, but when I try:

```
from SimpleCV import Camera
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name Camera
```

Any ideas?

Comment: in the python interpreter, does `import SimpleCV;'Camera' in dir(SimpleCV)` return True?

Comment: @James is it possible, in the first scenario,  for you to use `SimpleCV.Camera` or does that not even work?

Comment: Neither of those work. It acts like it can't find any of the modules (Image, Display, Camera, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to use SimpleCV from eclipse and you're getting these errors, perhaps you could try the instructions I posted in this question's answer: [SimpleCV Code Completion with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272914/simplecv-code-completion-with-eclipse/15843153#15843153) I'll paste the same info for you here:

My attempt at fixing their imports was to remove all those import *'s from their init.py file which helps with the code completion lag that it presents in eclipse. Then importing the SimpleCV egg directory (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\simplecv-1.3-py2.7.egg) into eclipse as an external library. After that, I was able to run this:

```
from SimpleCV.ImageClass import Image
```

Same goes for importing Color:

```
from SimpleCV.Color import Color
```

There are cyclical imports, so beware of those as they might bite you. I myself had one earlier while trying to import SimpleCV.Color before importing SimpleCV.ImageClass. Note, with the above instructions, I seem to be able to get code-completion from Eclipse.